# How to hook the abstract method hasSystemFeature?

Tags: android, subclass, abstract, xposed

I want to hook `PackageManager`'s `hasSystemFeature` system method. But this method is abstract. In fact, `PackageManager` itself is an abstract class. Hooking the method gives the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot hook abstract methods: public abstract boolean android.content.pm.PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)
```

Usually we call `context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(string)`, but I never know what the implementing subclass is! So what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Smali debugging to find that the right class to hook is

```
android.content.pm.IPackageManager.Stub.Proxy
```